# WPF DataGrid and DataGridTemplateColumn Header Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have an issue with a piece of code...

I have something like as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RowData,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          RowHeaderWidth="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.AreAllSelected}">
                    Select All
                </CheckBox>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>  
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It is in a View that is derived from the type UserControl -- for absolute sure.  For some reason, the binding fails on the CheckBox in the TemplateColumn Header.  What's unusual is that I have this code in other views -- and it works absolutely fine and without any issues.  I always create the ViewModel first, and pass it in as a parameter to the View, wherein the DataContext is set to the ViewModel upon construction, i.e.

```
View(ViewModel myViewModel)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = myViewModel;
}
```

The ViewModel has the AreAllSelected property on it, but I get the following error -- so I know it isn't finding the ancestor for some reason.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.AreAllSelected;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')

The weird thing is that, even though it doesn't work, when I use Snoop to view it, it will initially not work.  When I look into the Binding and delve into it, the Binding now works.

I'm wondering if it's some weird issue with how it's constructed at a Visual Tree level or what?  As I said prior -- I've done this several other times in other Views and they work fine.  There must be some weird thing I'm doing incorrectly...

Comment: Give `x:Name` to your UserControl and try binding using `ElementName` instead of `RelativeSource`.

Comment: Tried that one already -- it didn't work.  Going with the HeaderTemplate was the only way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the other way around:

```
View(ViewModel myViewModel)
{
   DataContext = myViewModel;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Btw you should use HeaderTemplate to template the header. Header alone shall only be for example a string value.

You placed your CheckBox instead. Thats not the usual way in wpf.

Comment: Oy!  Thanks for the peer programming.  I totally missed I was doing a Header instead of a HeaderTemplate.  **THAT** was the issue!

Comment: @Locke - `CheckBox` inside `Header` also works though. What was your exact problem?

Comment: @RohitVats CheckBoxes shall work inside Header but as I mentioned its not really ment to be used that way. Because like we see here sometmes the timing aint that perfect and your Binding doesnt update. Snoop forces refresh and then all of a sudden it works. :)

Comment: @dev - Can you please post a link validating your statement?

Comment: Just think about it. Its not best practice placing controls as DataContext. If binding tries to be initalized before controls template been created you end up having broken binding.